# Searching & difference of large sets of integers

Tags: java, algorithm

I have 2 large integer arrays. I have to get the difference of these arrays(i.e. elements in 2nd array, not in 1st or vice versa). I am implementing a linear search and storing the difference in an array. Is there any way I can do it faster (Linear time)?

Comment: are the arrays sorted ?, Can u use additional space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to get O(n+m) time if you put one array into a hash set and then run through the other array, probing the hash set. Of course, if your arrays were sorted, then you could have O(n+m) directly.

Comment: My arrays are sorted. Could you please elaborate or suggest some links to the hash set solution? I am new to this and I would like to learn more about it..

Comment: But if they are sorted, you don't need that. You need to go through both arrays only once in that case, O(n+m).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say possibly, depending on your over needs.  You could break the lists down into small sets and using threads process each set, combing the results back into a centralised pool.

While not overly difficult, you will need to some management in order to organise the results back into their correct order (as thread 2 may finish before thread 1) as well as monitor the process to know when it has completed.

You could take a look at the [Executors Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are good, but what about a set datastructure?

```
stromberg@aw50 ~ $ /usr/local/pypy-1.9/bin/pypy
Python 2.7.2 (341e1e3821ff, Jun 07 2012, 15:38:48)
[PyPy 1.9.0 with GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``<arigato> the AI state is indeed
close''
>>>> s1 = set(range(10))
>>>> s2 = set(range(5,15))
>>>> s1
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>>> s2
set([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
>>>> s1 - s2
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>>> s2 - s1
set([10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
>>>> s1 & s2
set([8, 9, 5, 6, 7])
>>>> s1 | s2
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
>>>>
```

I guess that's a convenient way, and fast for lists that fit in memory at the same time.

There are also things like on-disk BTrees, or bloom filters.

With the BTrees, you wouldn't have to fit everything in memory, and would do your differencing similarly to the merge step of merge sort.  They're basically an ordered database table.

For the bloom filters, they're great for if you need to filter down the number of things you need to consider; they're probabilistic, and can give answers like "this is definitely not in the set" and "this is almost certainly in the set".  The chief benefit of bloom filters is that they require very little memory (sometimes as little as one bit per element).  Nice implementations will allow you to specify your maximum allowable error probability.  EG, detecting *ix hard links is pretty much a set membership problem that bloom filters are really nice for - they give you a short list of likely hard links that can be quickly made 100% accurate afterward, since the number of hard links tends to be small, even if the number of actual files is huge.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything fancy.  If your arrays are sorted then a single pass through each array is enough to get the diff.  Just keep an index into each array and if the indices point to equal elements, increment both indices, otherwise add the lower element to your return array and increment its index.

Here is code, in Go, that does this: http://play.golang.org/p/VZgGWmu-aO

This solution takes O(n+m) time, and O(n+m) space, and you can't really do better than that.  Also it doesn't have the overhead that a solution involving hash tables would have.

Answer (score 0):

This is a blunt way of achieving your aim:

```
public static Set<Integer> foundInFirstButNotSecond(int[] first,
        int[] second) {
    Set<Integer> secondSet = new HashSet<Integer>(second.length);
    for (Integer i :
            second) {
        secondSet.add(i);
    }
    Set<Integer> resultSet = new HashSet<Integer>(first.length);
    for (Integer j :
            first) {
        if (!secondSet.contains(j)) {
            // Current integer from first not found in second
            resultSet.add(j);
        }
    }
    return resultSet;
}
```

Note that it returns a Set rather than an array, but you can easily modify this code to produce an array instead if that suits you better.

As an example, if you call this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] first = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int[] second = new int[]{5, 6, 7, 8};
    System.out.println("In first but not second: " + ArrayCompare.
            foundInFirstButNotSecond(first, second));
}
```

you'll get a Set with content [1, 2, 3, 4]. (Note that HashSet does not guarantee any particular order, so you could just as well get a disordered variation of this.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two arrays are sorted,you can use two slinding pointers to find the difference.The time complexity is O(n+m) , and space O(max(n,m)).

```
    void set_difference(std::vector<int> & array1,std::vector<int> & array2,std::vector<int> & output ) 
{
    auto index1 =  0 ;
    auto index2 = 0 ;
    while (index1 != array1.size() & index2 != array2.size()) 
    {       //since the arrays are sorted, we can stop looking right when we find a number bigger
        while ((array1[index1] < array2[index2]) & index2 != array2.size() )  
            index2++ ;
        if (array1[index1] != array2[index2]) //array1[index1] is not array2
            output.push_back(array1[index1]);
        index1++ ;
    }
}
```